# returning duplicate results from object.keys in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop over my nameDef object and return its values to the console log once. However it is showing up 4 different times and I am not to sure why.

Please see the image below which shows the error I am getting

Please ignore:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3pdt.png)

here is my code:

```
const createUnitTestLandingPage = props => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
  const targetObject = query.get('object')

  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)

  const [unitTestTemplates, setUnitTestTemplates] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUnitTests() {
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await verifiedGet(`get_unit_test_templates/0/50`, user.user)
      if(results.status === 0) {
        const templates = [...results.data]
        const sortedTemplates = templates.sort((a, b) => a.display_order - b.display_order)
        setUnitTestTemplates(sortedTemplates)
      } else if(results.status >=20 && results.status <=30) {
        snackbar.statusCheck(results)
        user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
      } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }

    getUnitTests()
  }, [])

  const onTestTypeClick = (id) => {
    if(targetObject) props.history.push(`/createtest?id=${id}&object=${targetObject}`)
    else props.history.push(`/createtest?id=${id}`)
  }

    const nameDef = {
      REASONABLENESS: 'Verifies that the data aligns to operational context. E.g. a birth date of 01/01/01 is valid, but generally not reasonable',
      COMPLETENESS: 'Verifies that all necessary data is present in a dataset.',
      VALIDITY: 'Verifies that the data conforms to the format of its definition',
      UNIQUENESS: 'Verifies that an attribute is unique and free of duplication ',
      TIMELINESS: 'Verifies that data is up to date and available for use as required by the busines',
      CONSISTENCY: 'Verifies that the data is free of contradictions. Especially where data is pulled from multiple environments',
      INTEGRITY: 'Verifies that data is accurate and consistent across its lifecycle. Each time data is replicated or transferred, it should remain intact and unaltered between updates. Error checking methods should be used to ensure that the data is transferred without alteration.',
      RECONCILIATION: 'Verifies the accuracy of financial attributes and measures as they are transformed through the various layers of the data platform. This can take the form of an aggregated sum comparison which prevents any mismatch caused by changing the granularity of qualifying dimensions.'

    }

    console.log('from', Object.keys(nameDef))

  return (
    <PageWrapper title='Create Unit Tests' instructions='Choose a test template' instructionsLeft>
      <div className='Card'>
        <div className='TableTopbar CreateUnitTestsGrid'>
          <div>Test Template</div>
          <div>Typical DQ Domain</div>
        </div>
 
      {unitTestTemplates.map(test =>

        <React.Fragment key={test.id}>
          {!test.space_above ? null :  
            <div style={{backgroundColor: 'var(--grey-bg-color)', height: '25px'}}/>
          }
          <div className='Table CreateUnitTestsGrid' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => onTestTypeClick(test.id)}>
            <div>{test.name}</div>
            <div style={{width: '150px'}}>
              {!test.typical_dq_domain ? null :
              <Tooltip title={'hello'} >
                <Chip 
                  label={test.typical_dq_domain}
                  className='Badge' 
                  style={{
                    width: '100%', 
                    color: getColor('fg', test.typical_dq_domain), 
                    backgroundColor: getColor('bg', test.typical_dq_domain)
                  }}
                />
              </Tooltip>
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )} 
      </div>
    </PageWrapper>
  )
}

export default withRouter(createUnitTestLandingPage)
```

Comment: Your `console.log` is in the main function body of the functional component. Which means every time the component re-renders, it will print. In your `useEffect` it looks like your doing a few things that would cause a re-render, so that's what's causing the multiple `console.log`s

Comment: The console log is in the functional component body, so anytime react renders the component for any reason the log will be invoked. Note here that render here means during the "render phase" when react renders the virtual DOM tree in order to do a diff comparison before moving on to the "commit phase" and write out any changes to the actual DOM. If you want to log anything, use a lifecycle method executed in the "commit phase" like `useEffect`.